# javascript variable in hidden form to another php script

Tags: javascript, php

I am sending a javascript value in a hidden form to a php script. This is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(e) {
var mydata = 3;
if ($(this).is(':not([data-submit="true"])'))
{
        $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="foo" value=mydata>');
        $('form').data('submit', 'true').submit();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
}
})
})
```

In my php script, I am accessing the value like below.

```
$src1= $_POST['foo'];
echo $src1;
```

I have initialized `mydata` to 3. I am expecting the output to be 3 in my php script,  but instead I am getting the string **mydata**.

Comment: You've only shown us the code that works. Show us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: mydata will be consider as String not variable that you are passing.

Comment: It is very important to note that your jQuery is ***critically*** incorrect. It will break instantly if you have more than one `<form>` on your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the problem was that you was passing `mydata` as string instead of as the variable itself, you need to concatenate correctly to pass the Value to the Value, as it works.

**Using this Code:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(e) {
var mydata = 3;
if ($(this).is(':not([data-submit="true"])'))
{
        $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="'+mydata+'">');
        $('form').data('submit', 'true').submit();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
}
})
})
```

You see that now, the real value into `value=""` html attribute of the `<input>` will be `3` instead of `"mydata"`.

This way you will be able to access `$_POST['foo'];` on the php page, getting `3`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
  $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="'+mydata+'">');
```

Here mydata is consider as variable not String.

Answer (score 2):

You don't concatenate the string correctly, try this way :

```
$('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="' + mydata +'">');
```

Comment: value needs to be mydata, not name

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript strings do not interpolate variables. They can't - JavaScript identifiers do not start with sigils, so there is no way to distinguish a variable name in a string from a piece of text.

The quick, dirty and unsafe approach is to break apart your string and concatenate it:

```
$('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="' + mydata + '">');
```

But this will fail if `mydata` contains a `"` and could give weird results if it contains a `&`, so build you HTML using DOM (or jQuery wrappers around that).

```
$('form').append(
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'foo').attr('value', mydata)
);
```